# Continuously differentiable $f$ over $D\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ constant iff $\text{grad} f(x)=0$ for all $x\in D$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on $D\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ constant iff $\text{grad} f(x)=0$ for
>   all $x\in D$

$\Leftarrow$ is trivial,

"$\Rightarrow$" One can connect two points in in $D$ by a polygonal chain. Applying the mean value theorem to each of the partial sections [of the polygonal chain] proves the statement.

I don't understand what this has to do with $f$ being constant?

Comment: What do you mean by $f\in D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$? It doesn't make any sense the way you've written it. You are essentially saying $f$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Ah, that's wrong, give me a sec.

Comment: On each of the line segments you can use the fact that if $g: [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ has derivative $0$ then $g(a)=g(b)$.

Comment: Why is that the case? If $M\subset D$ is a polygonal chain, so $a,b\in M$ with $a=a_0,a_1,...,a_n=b$ exist such that $S_{a_{k-1},a_k}:=\{x\in M : x=a_{k-1}+t(a_{k}-a_{k-1}) : t\in [0,1]\} \subset M$ for $1\leq k \leq n$. For each partial section, $t$ is the derivative, or am I wrong?

Comment: What is $D$? Presumably open and connected for otherwise the statement fails.

Comment: $D$ is an open, nonempty and connected space

Comment: I think $\Rightarrow$ is trivial and the converse requires a proof.